# Occurrences of floating point errors and how to prevent them

Tags: python, floating-point

I have this program which calculates the total for all the values entered by the user:

```
result = 0
for i in range(3):
    n = float(input("Enter a value: "))
    result = result + n
print(result)
```

If I entered in the values, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, the output will be correct and print a result of 3.8. However, it seems when I enter in three floating point values which are all the same, I will get a floating point error. For example, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2 will print out 3.5999999999999996.

Why does this seem to happen? Is there a way that I can prevent it?

Comment: Basically, if you need precise arithmetic don't use `float`s.  Instead, use something like the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: `decimal` isn't exact either, though. Mostly, it's just decimal, so its imprecision lines up better with human intuition. (It also offers configurable precision and a bunch of other advanced options, but none of them make the problem of rounding go away.)

Comment: The term *floating point error* usually means an exception like divide by zero or arccosine of too large a number.  What you are describing is not that sort of error, but an unexpected result which comes from misunderstanding what a float is.  The fundamental issue is that `0.1` cannot be exactly expressed in a `float` or `double` just like `1/3` cannot be exactly expressed with decimal notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `float` does a lot more decimal numbers, for more information check this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), so you should do the below:

```
result = 0
for i in range(3):
    n = float(input("Enter a value: "))
    result = result + n
print('{0:.1f}'.format(result))
```

Output:

```
Enter a value: 1.2
Enter a value: 1.2
Enter a value: 1.2
3.6
```

Or:

```
result = 0
for i in range(3):
    n = float(input("Enter a value: "))
    result = result + n
print('%.1f'%result)
```

Output:

```
Enter a value: 1.1
Enter a value: 1.1
Enter a value: 1.1
3.3
```

## `decimal` module:

Try this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
result = 0
for i in range(3):
    n = Decimal(input("Enter a value: "))
    result = result + n
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Enter a value: 2.1
Enter a value: 2.1
Enter a value: 2.1
6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the floating point numbers does not have an exact representation, for more information check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

If precision is critical for you, you can use python [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).